# How to set Left Jusitify on by default when content entered is entered in HtmlEditorExtender of AjaxControlToolkit?

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I want to set the left justify on by default when I enter the content in the HtmlEditorExtender control of AjaxControlToolkit.

By default when my page is loaded and when I go on to enter any content in the editor it is entered as center aligned.

So how could I set Left justify property ON.

Answer (score 0):

This property comes ON by default (I just tested it myself). Make sure you do not have some other css class interfering with your divs, since the Ajax extender actually renders the editor as such.

Good luck!

Comment: I don't know what went wrong previously it was coming left justified but now its centered... I am not able to sort it out.

Comment: @Maninder - consider either accepting this answer or posting and accepting your own.

Answer (score 0):

For me, a simple 'td align="center"' was causing this issue. I just replaced 'center' with 'left' and the problem was solved! :)

Comment: Where can I find the 'td align="center"' attribute so that i can also modify and see whether its working on my side or not.

Comment: Sometimes I mix server and client codes. For example: mixing an 'asp:TextBox ..' with an Html tag such as 'table'(with the above 'td align="center"'). My example apply to these cases(and I don't know if this will always work). You must make a search on your code for situations like that.